# jQuery Animate Increase Number Effect Slow Down Near End

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want change animation speed after x seconds, from fast to slow until end. However, this one doesn't works.

Please help me.

```js
$('.holder').each(function() {
  var speed = 15000;

  function change() {
    speed = 2000;
  }
  setTimeout(change, 2000);
  $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
    Counter: $(this).data('number')
  }, {
    duration: speed,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function(now) {
      $(this).text(Math.ceil(now).toLocaleString('en'));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 class="holder" data-number="1000000"></h3>
```

Comment: That's because the original value of `speed` has already been used to instantiate the jQuery animation instance, so modifying it will not work. jQuery does not also seem to have an API to modify animation config once it has started. Will you be interested in exploring the use of plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, your code does not work because the original `speed` value has been used to instantiate the jQuery animation queue, and you cannot modify it and assume jQuery animation will "watch" for updated settings. There also seems to be no API for jQuery `.animate()` method to allow for changes in animation settings when it is already running.

The best solution will be to actually author your own easing function. Since it can be mathematically complicated, there are actually third-party plugins such as [**bez**](https://github.com/rdallasgray/bez) that you can use. The plugin returns a cubic-bezier function that allows you to set how the values should be tweened/interpolated.

If you want your values to change quickly at the start and slower towards the end, an example cubic bezier curve you can use is [`cubic-bezier(.20, 1, .20, 1)`](http://cubic-bezier.com/#.2,1,.2,1):

[image: Cubiz bezier curve using the parameters 0.2, 1, 0,2 1]

p/s: You can use this site to play around with different parameters to get the interpolation you want: http://cubic-bezier.com

As mentioned above, if you're using the $.bez plugin to create an easing function, it is as simple as calling: `$.bez([0.2,1,0.2,1])`. Simply provide this as the `easing` parameter in your `.animate` method:

```
$('.holder').each(function() {
  setTimeout(change, 2000);
  $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
    Counter: $(this).data('number')
  }, {
    duration: 15000,
    easing: $.bez([0.2,1,0.2,1]),
    step: function(now) {
      $(this).text(Math.ceil(now).toLocaleString('en'));
    }
  });
});
```

See proof-of-concept below:

```js
/*!
 * Bez @VERSION
 * http://github.com/rdallasgray/bez
 *
 * A plugin to convert CSS3 cubic-bezier co-ordinates to jQuery-compatible easing functions
 *
 * With thanks to Nikolay Nemshilov for clarification on the cubic-bezier maths
 * See http://st-on-it.blogspot.com/2011/05/calculating-cubic-bezier-function.html
 *
 * Copyright @YEAR Robert Dallas Gray. All rights reserved.
 * Provided under the FreeBSD license: https://github.com/rdallasgray/bez/blob/master/LICENSE.txt
 */
(function(factory) {
  if (typeof exports === "object") {
    factory(require("jquery"));
  } else if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
    define(["jquery"], factory);
  } else {
    factory(jQuery);
  }
}(function($) {
  $.extend({ bez: function(encodedFuncName, coOrdArray) {
    if ($.isArray(encodedFuncName)) {
      coOrdArray = encodedFuncName;
      encodedFuncName = 'bez_' + coOrdArray.join('_').replace(/\./g, 'p');
    }
    if (typeof $.easing[encodedFuncName] !== "function") {
      var polyBez = function(p1, p2) {
        var A = [null, null], B = [null, null], C = [null, null],
            bezCoOrd = function(t, ax) {
              C[ax] = 3 * p1[ax], B[ax] = 3 * (p2[ax] - p1[ax]) - C[ax], A[ax] = 1 - C[ax] - B[ax];
              return t * (C[ax] + t * (B[ax] + t * A[ax]));
            },
            xDeriv = function(t) {
              return C[0] + t * (2 * B[0] + 3 * A[0] * t);
            },
            xForT = function(t) {
              var x = t, i = 0, z;
              while (++i < 14) {
                z = bezCoOrd(x, 0) - t;
                if (Math.abs(z) < 1e-3) break;
                x -= z / xDeriv(x);
              }
              return x;
            };
        return function(t) {
          return bezCoOrd(xForT(t), 1);
        }
      };
      $.easing[encodedFuncName] = function(x, t, b, c, d) {
        return c * polyBez([coOrdArray[0], coOrdArray[1]], [coOrdArray[2], coOrdArray[3]])(t/d) + b;
      }
    }
    return encodedFuncName;
  }});
}));


$('.holder').each(function() {
  $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
    Counter: $(this).data('number')
  }, {
    duration: 15000,
    easing: $.bez([0.2,1,0.2,1]),
    step: function(now) {
      $(this).text(Math.ceil(now).toLocaleString('en'));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 class="holder" data-number="1000000"></h3>
```